# -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] crashes with no error in console..while click the button

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode4

PushViewController crashes with no error in the console, but I do get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error in Xcode. The crash doesn't happen until after the view controller has been pushed... but the view its pushing is empty... no code to mess up.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X62jD.png

Comment: Put breakpoint before pushing controller and see if "clientprogress" is nil

Comment: I suggest you to check your `Client_Progress` class to see whether there is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

put the below code to `callStackSymbols` in `main.m` and then see what it return

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      @autoreleasepool 
      {
           @try
           {
                return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
           }
           @catch (NSException *exception)
           {
               NSLog(@"Stack Trace:: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);
           }
      }
}
```

Comment: again getting same error with some     malloc: *** error for object 0xa27e800: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
BodyResolution(9973,0xb03f8000) malloc: *** error for object 0xa27ea00: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Answer (score 1):

It seems that *self.navigationController* doesn't exist at the moment of receiving pushViewController. To clarify problem you can enable "zomby objects" in your project.

Go to  the "Product" menu, Scheme >, select "Edit Scheme", go to the "Run YOUR_APP.app" in the left panel, and the "Arguments" tab on the right. Then add *NSZombieEnabled* to the "Environment Variables" section and set the value to YES.

Also there is the checkbox at the "Diagnostics" tab of the "Run" - "Enable Zombie Objects".

Without "zombies": EXC_BAD_ACCESS

With "zombies": -[UIViewController release]: message sent to deallocated instance